# How do you integrate $\frac{12}{1 - \cos(2x)}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int \frac{12 \, dx}{1 - \cos(2x)}$$

I know that the answer is [image]. But how do you get there?

Also, please note that this problem must be solved **without** integration by parts.

Comment: $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2 x$.

Comment: Tangent half-angle substitution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution) works for more general rational trigonometric functions.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that 
$$\frac{1}{1 - \cos t} = \frac{1 + \cos t}{\sin^2 t} = \csc^2 t + \frac{\cos t}{\sin^2 t}$$

Another substitution is now appropriate.

Comment: Your process does not match the answer.

Comment: This process will give an equivalent answer to whatever key you have. You may need to do some algebra though.

Comment: @Ordinary Owl. The answer is equivalent to -6cot(x) + c, if you'd like it in terms of x rather than 2x.

Comment: I was thinking along a similar approach, where I immediately wrote it as a function of x, (not 2x),  then integrated that.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$
\frac{1}{1-\cos 2x}=\frac{1}{\sin^2 x+\cos^2x-\cos^2x +\sin^2 x}
$$
and 
$$
\int \frac{1}{\sin^2 x}\,dx
$$
is well known.

Comment: Where did the 12 disappear off to?

Comment: @OrdinaryOwl Multiplying by a constant is left to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Another way, changing variable first $x=\frac t2$ $$I=\int \frac{12 \, dx}{1 - \cos(2x)}=\int\frac{6\,dt}{1-\cos (t)}$$ Now,tangent half-angle substitution $u=\tan(\frac t 2)$ makes $$I=\int\frac{6\,du}{u^2}=-\frac{6}{u}+C$$ Now, backwards to $x$ would lead to the solution.$$I=-\frac{6}{u}+C=-\frac{6}{\tan(\frac t 2)}+C=-\frac{6}{\tan(x)}+C$$ noticing that $$-6 \frac{(\cos (2 x)+1)}{\sin (2 x)}=-6\frac{2\cos^2(x)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}=-6\frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)}=-\frac{6}{\tan(x)}$$